# Swift 4 KeyPath On Objects of Different Type

Tags: swift, keypaths

I have 2 types, `A` and `B` that implement the same methods and have the same properties on them. I have defined an extension to fetch a value in a sub property for each of `A` and `B`. I want to know if there is a way to reduce those 2 extensions down to 1 method. Imagine there are many more types like `A` and `B` so the code duplication problem becomes much worse.

Update: `A` and `B` are generated along with many others like them. The original plan is to avoid writing extensions at all for `A` or `B`. I don't know if this is possible but I was told I could use KeyPaths for this. The properties names must be different. This is a byproduct of the code generation

```
struct A {
    var something: Common
}

struct B {
    var somethingElse: Common
}

struct Common {
    var value1: String
    var value2: String
}

extension A {
    func valueFor(condition: Bool) -> String {
      return condition ? self.something.value1 : self.something.value2
    }
}

extension B {
    func valueFor(condition: Bool) -> String {
      return condition ? self.somethingElse.value1 : self.somethingElse.value2
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could probably use KeyPaths. I notice that you mention them in your question title but there are no key paths anywhere in your code. That's quite telling, I think.

Comment: If it would have been okay for struct B's property to be called `something` (like struct A's property), rather than `somethingElse`, you should be very clear about that in your question, as it is obviously crucial.

Comment: @matt thanks, I have updated the question. Yes their property names must remain different

Comment: @drfear now with updated question I'd recommend check about swift generics https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Comment: @inokey I am familiar with generics, can you explain at a high level what you are thinking?

Comment: @drfear in your idea, do you want to know which of the A or B struct properties adopt Common?

Answer (score 2):

I think protocols are the solution for your problem. They help to make code more generic.

```
protocol CommonContaining {

    var common: Common { get set }

    func valueFor(condition: Bool) -> String {
      return condition ? self.common.value1 : self.common.value2
    }
}


struct A {
    var something: Common
}

struct B {
    var somethingElse: Common
}


extension A: CommonContaining {
     var common: Common {
         return something
    }
}

extension B: CommonContaining {
     var common: Common {
         return somethingElse
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought of that too, but now you are forcing A and B to use the same name for their property, and that seems to be against the spirit of the question. (It might not be, of course.)

Comment: A and B are both generated and the properties have different names :(. Imagine structs A through Z. There are about 20 of them

Comment: @drfear But you have to have a way to retrieve the `Common` value from your generated types.

Comment: There's no problem with that. You're just extending their functionality with a common property while they still have their own properties in tact. You're basically specifying that in case you need a common property use `something` for `A` and `somethingElse` for `B`

Comment: @matt The `common` property could be declared `fileprivate` so that outside code would not see it. You can even declare the same property elsewhere without conflict.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll mull these over. I got a tip from someone telling me to use KeyPaths and I am stumped as to how that would work. Maybe they are crazy

Comment: @drfear please check the edited version of the answer. Note that `CommonContaining` only extends functionality preserving the original structure of `A` and `B`.

Comment: I want to avoid writing duplicate extensions for A and B

Answer (score -1):

From what i have understand, if the method is related to Common struct then you should implement this method in the struct itself or to create extension to the struct :

```
struct A
{
    var something: Common
}

struct B
{
    var somethingElse: Common
}

struct Common
{
    var value1: String
    var value2: String

    func valueFor(condition: Bool) -> String {
    return condition ? self.value1 : self.value2 }
}

var object_1 = A(something: Common(value1: "1", value2: "1"))
var object_2 = B(somethingElse: Common(value1: "1", value2: "2"))

print(object_1.something.valueFor(condition: true))
print(object_2.somethingElse.valueFor(condition: false))
```

Good luck.

Comment: I don't see any logic related to the original question behind this implementation.

Comment: Why ? he wants to make only one method rather than duplicating the code !

Comment: I see that method is related to common struct not to A or B ! What is your opinion ?

Comment: Why then use an extension on `Common` if this method could be added to the original struct? Even with that, your code implies that user of a `valueFor` explicitly knows which of the properties of original struct has target functionality.

Comment: The original plan was to avoid writing extensions at all for `A` or `B`. But idk how that is possible

Comment: @inokey you are right. you can implement this method in common struct. extension is another way !

Comment: you should make extension or implement the method in the common struct.